# What is the correct procedure for removing and replacing the oil pan on a 2006 Corolla?

Tags: toyota, oil-change, corolla, torque, oil-pan

I believe there is a clog in the oil pan that is preventing me from fully draining it.  I'm too cheap to buy a copy of the Hayne's manual for the 2006 Toyota Corolla.  The specific information I am missing is:

- sequence for removing and replacing the oil pan bolts
- proper torque for said bolts
- do I use sealant or a gasket?
- if using a gasket, does it need to be lubricated (as one would lubricate an oil filter's gasket)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an article on ToyoNation explaining what you need to do: [Link](http://www.toyotanation.com/forum/132-9th-gen-corolla-1st-gen-matrix-2003-2008/1128857-diy-2003-2008-corolla-matrix-pontiac-vibe-oil-pan-replacement-pics.html)

Generally, removing the bolts you don't need a sequence. When torquing them back up, you want to do them up in a diagonal star pattern, as you would with your wheel lugs etc.

This guide recommends using a toyota sealant, which is probably about right. Any RTV sealant that's at the right spec (heat and oil resistant) will do the trick. [RTV Grey](https://www.permatex.com/products/gasketing/permatex-ultra-grey-rigid-high-torque-rtv-silicone-gasket-maker/) etc.

Luckily on a lot of FWD cars, the pan/sump is pretty easily accessible... It's not a terrible job.

Edit: If you get a magnetic poking stick (they are like a dollar at most car parts stores) you should poke that into the oil drain hole before pulling the car apart. You might dislodge the sludge, making your job easier. Or you might pull out the remains of your big ends, so you won't need to worry about pulling the oil pan off anyway ;)